# How do I install Ubuntu on an HP Touchsmart 600?

Tags: 12.04, installation, hp

I have a hp touchsmart 600 pc series. I tried to install the lastest version of ubuntu (12.04 LTS, 64bits) but it would not install. I popped in the cd and the menu asked for a reboot. Which I did.

As ubuntu was about to install(purple background with 2 symbols underneth) the screen was dark and a prompt kept blinking for like over 10 minutes. So I turned off my pc and loaded my window os. I ran ubuntu again and used the help install feature. Needless to say the same thing happen again! does ubuntu work on hp touchsmart computers?

Answer (score 1):

Try using nomodeset during the install. When you pop in the cd, try pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> and select nomodset or press <kbd>F4</kbd>. If that doesn't work, try using unetbootin and install via USB. A third option would be the text installer.